# Adding a comma separated strings to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to add comma separated spreadsheet values to an array using Google Apps Script. Let's call the cells I'm looking at A1, B1 and C1. All of them contain text, to be more precise these are the exact values:

A1="a"; B1="b,c,d"; C1="e"

Using the function below I get the following result in my console

```
[[a,b,c,d,e]]
```

If I want to paste them back into the spreadsheet I end up with

A1="a"; B1="b"; C1="c"; D1="d"; E1="e";

This problem is probably related to the comma separated values in B1 because the array should actually look similar to this:

```
[["a","b,c,d","e"]]
```

Replacing the commas is no option. Any ideas to tackle my problem are appreciated!

Code snippet:

```
function valuesToArray(){
            
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var worksheet = ss.getSheetByName("Worksheet");
var range = worksheet.getRange(1,1,1,3).getValues();

Logger.log(range);
    
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `getRange(1,1,3,1)` be selecting A1, A2, A3? Either way, you'll just have to get the cells individually to get their value

Comment: What will log for range.length and range[0].length?

Comment: @George Thanks for your remark, I changed it to the right format! The problem is, that I have a large spreadsheet and extracting single values will make the script very slow

Comment: Utilities.parseCsv()

Comment: The array is always 2 dimensional [[a,b,c...]]

Comment: @Cooper edited the arrays, can you explain a bit more what you mean by Utilities.parseCsv() ?

Comment: Look it up. It’s in the documentation.

Comment: I did, hence the question. Your solution summarizes the cell entries in individual arrays within an array, but this is unfortunately not what I was looking for

Comment: How are you "pasting  back" the values into the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadCsv(csv) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Worksheet');
  const vs=Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```